# Gridview custom paging inside wizard control doesn't work correct in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, paging, wizard

I have a page where guests can be selected.

This page contains an update panel, within the update panel there is a wizard control and in the wizard control there is a gridview (Panel-> Update Panel -> wizard control -> gridview)

Now the paging doesn't work well, I searched the internet for answers but I didn't find the right answer. I use custom paging.

When I want to change the pagenumber (to the second or last page) it works fine. But when I want to select a row or go to another page, the gridview doesn't work correct. When I select A row on the second or last page (other page's don't work) the selected guest (item) is always one of the first page. When I want change to another page (from the second or last page) it doesn't work and stays on the selected page.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

part of the code:

```
               <asp:Panel ID="PnlRe" Style="display: none; ... >
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtPnlDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Wizard ID="wzd" runat="server" ... >
            ...
            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Naam">
                        ...
                           <asp:Gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                               DataKeyNames="GastID,Versie" DataSourceID="odsGasten" EmptyDataText="...."
                               OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="Gridview1_PageIndexChanging"
                               OnPageSizeChanging="Gridview1_PageSizeChanging" OnSearching="Gridview1_Searching"
                               OnSorting="Gridview1_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="Gridview1_RowDataBound"
                               CausesValidation="False" meta:resourcekey="..." PagerType="Custom"
                               ShowFilter="True" ShowInsertRecord="True" ShowPageSizer="True" UseSubmitBehaviour="False">
                               <Columns>
                                   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" meta:resourcekey="...">
                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandName="Select" CausesValidation="False" SkinID="uprowbutton"
                                               ToolTip="..." ID="ImgBtnSelect" meta:resourcekey="...">
                                           </asp:ImageButton>
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                   </asp:TemplateField>
                                   ... Boundfields ...
                               </Columns>
                           </asp:Gridview>
                        ...
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                    ... 
    </asp:Wizard>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
protected void Gridview1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    this.odsGasten.FilterExpression = searchText;
    this.Gridview1.DataBind();
    this.UpdtPnlDetail.Update();
}
```

Comment: You're using a conditional UpdatePanel but I don't see any triggers. Did you omit them or do you have no triggers registered? If you need to leave the UpdatePanel as conditional I think you need to register the PageIndexChanging event as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tricky way to achieve this, you have to manipulate your data source.
 for example if you are using a datatable you have to select first ten elements of dt and bind it to grid, and when next button is clicked get next ten elements of dt and bind it to gridview. this will make your task easy and will get more performance for your  page.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this.GridView1.DataBind() is called in GridView1_PageIndexChanging, but where is the currentPageIndex stored and updated with the page index you want to navigate to and when in the process is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a viewstate problem.

You need to make sure that between Init and Load you have the grid's source set, either from viewstate or from a new bind-ing.